# Можно ли в javascript'e вызвать метод действия?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Могу ли я вызвать из функции, метод действия??

```
function OnSuccess() {
//например: html.Action("Index","Cart"); или html.Patrial("Index", "Cart");
       }
```

Comment: а какой результат ты ожидаешь?

Comment: ну, например вызову какой-то частичный метод который обновит мне какое-то содержание на странице

Comment: тогда смотри только в сторону AJAX